# Restiction in directory when deploy laravel app. open_basedir restriction for lang directory

Tags: laravel, web, vps

I tried to deploy a laravel web in Windows server 2018. At the moment that I load the webpage error 500.

The log file said:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(C:\inetpub\vhosts\my-web.com\resources\lang/de.json) is not within the allowed path(s): (C:/Inetpub/vhosts/my-web.com\;C:\Windows\Temp) in C:\inetpub\vhosts\my-web.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php:23

I tried to give all permissions in Plesk but doesn't help. I tried to print a simple "Hello world" and it works. Do I miss something?

I also did the recommendation from Plesk without success.

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000278993-A-website-hosted-in-Plesk-is-not-accessible-open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-File-is-not-within-the-allowed-path-s-

PHP version 7.3.14
Laravel 6

Answer (score 0):

In Plesk go to *php settings* and add *:{WEBSPACEROOT}* to the **open_basedir** so laravel can access to file in root.